# How to insert values to a table from user input

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I have created a database in PostgreSQL and succeeded creating a connection between them and also to have the tables created from Java source code.

My question is how can I insert values to these tables that come from a user input.
I have searched google enough but haven't found something that could really explain me what i need to do.

Comment: Could you provide more information such as what libraries you are using and some code snippets?

Comment: I use the standar JDK library along with postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc3.jar file in order to be able to establish the connection.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your method that handles user input you would do either an INSERT or UPDATE query.  Here's a modified example from the [docs](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/93/query.html):

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
String query_st = "INSERT INTO user_info_table VALUES ('"+user_id+"', '"+age+"', "+height+");";
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query_st);
while (rs.next())
{
   System.out.print("Column 1 returned ");
   System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
} rs.close();
st.close();
```

This assumes you have a table 'user_into_table' that has three columns.

Comment: In the interests of showing newbies how to do things ***the right way*** you really should have used a `PreparedStatement` and a parameterized query. (No downvote... this time... just a scolding. ;)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

```
   try (PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO employees VALUES (?,?)")) {

     pstmt.setBigDecimal(1, inputFromUser) <---- injection safe
     pstmt.setInt(2, inputFromUser) <---- injection safe
     ...
   } // Auto close.
```

The most important is to use question mark of prepared statements instead of string concat, concat allows users to inject sql into your queries.